# How do I get rid of this error while using npm package in client side JS?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, socket.io, npm-package

I was learning socket.io and when I reached the client side part, I installed a package called socket.io-client as per my instructor. When I tried to use it in my client side JS, it threw me an error. My socket.io is configured to run in the port 3000. This is my first time trying to use npm packages in the client side JS.
My instructor was this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKEqqIO7n-k&t=96s
The error reads out like this:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "socket.io-client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Here is my code:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    import {io} from "/server.js";
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
```

this will make it work as you would have required the library on a different file